# how curl retrieves a url with # and ! symbols in it?

Tags: ajax, curl

I was considering using curl to retrieve a page from a url(http://bbs.byr.cn/#!board/JobInfo?p=3) but ended up getting a notice from bash like

```
$ curl bbs.byr.cn/#!article/JobInfo/102321
bash: !article/JobInfo/102321: event not found
```

this url is accessible in my browser window, how can I write a curl command line that works on this url?

Comment: Everything beyond the # is not part of the URL sent to the server...

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not possible that stuff after the hashtag (#) is just handled by JavaScript on the client side. Curl cannot execute JavaScript. You can put that URL in quotes to get the static part of the page, but this is however surly not that what you want.

If you observe the traffic of that page in Firebug you will see that the url `http://bbs.byr.cn/board/JobInfo?p=3` will be downloaded. This file you can download to get your results.

Comment: This is very helpful.Is there any possibility to use the url part following the hashtag, namely "!article/JobInfo/102321" in this case, and find the corresponding javascript snippet concerning the client handling as mentioned in your answer, then use some sort of javascript to get the real desired page content? after all, I'm just  trying to write some sort of spider program that keeps track of information updates on a forum, I need to get the newly posted threads of everyday, is the the above stated method available for me?

Comment: That depends on the source code of that page. Just now I'm using a mobile so I cannot check this now. In general I would observe the AJAX requests in Firebug there you can see what happens.

Comment: I took a look it seems that just `http://bbs.byr.cn/board/JobInfo?p=3` seems to be downloded. That should be easy :-)